# How to set the imageView property in a UITableCellView to show only a background color?

Tags: ios, uitableview, background, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a custom class inheriting from `UITableViewCell` class that shows either an image (left to the title) or a generic dark-colored square if the image is not available). The following code shows a dark square on a light-colored cell background:

```
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(11, 6, 40, 40)];
[imageView setBackgroundColor:kBackgroundGreyColour];
[cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
```

However, instead of creating a custom subview in each table cell I would rather like to use the existing imageView property of the generic `UITableViewCell` class and modify it somehow to show the square as the code above does. This is what I am trying at this moment:

```
UIImageView* iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(11, 6, 40, 40)];
[iv setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
self.imageView.hidden = NO;
self.imageView.opaque = iv.opaque;
self.imageView.alpha = iv.alpha;
self.imageView.image = iv.image;
[self bringSubviewToFront:self.imageView];
[self.imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

I added all those lines to set as many of the existing `UIImageView` properties to the same values as the created `UIImageView` instance in the first code snippet, and yet the second code snippet doesn't show any dark square. It just doesn't show anything at all and the cell looks like there is just the light background and no image view visible. But I see that the imageView property is not nil so executing all those lines of code in the second snippet should show something?

However, as soon as I assign a new image to the imageView property (e.g. self.imageView.image = [[UIImage alloc] init...], the square shows the assigned image without problems.

Edit: Just a note that in the second case I am setting the frame of the imageView in layoutSubview function, e.g.:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(11, 6, 40, 40);
}
```

So my questions are:
1. Which properties of the existing imageView property I would need to set and to what values so that the code will show a square filled with a specific color (like the first snippet of code does)?

2. Is there a way of creating the `UIImage` programatically so that it shows only a background color without any image associated with it (and which I could use to set the imageView.image property to show that color).
3. Is it possible to replace the existing imageView property in a `UITableViewCell` class with a custom view without adding a custom subview (like the first code snippet did), so that I can show a placeholder UIView with a background color when the image is not available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your code doesn't work, is as you guessed; Because when you set the background colour of an imageview, it doesn't create anything on the image property.
And, you've figured out that you can't directly set the imageview property of the cell either.

I'd say your best bet, is the former option; To create a UIImage programmatically.
Although, I'd highly suggest simply creating one in your favourite image editing software then including it in the bundle. It makes for easy replacement later, for when you may get a better image, and next to no code and effort required to replace.

But if you still wish to do it all programmatically, it's not as simple as you'd hope.

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(11, 6, 40, 40);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [kBackgroundGreyColour CGColor]);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

self.imageview.image = image;
```

Should do the trick.
This defines the image size, creates a graphics context (think of it as a canvas), picks your grey colour to use, paints the canvas with it, then scans it into your computer into the small little size you wanted.

The little green imp does it all behind the screen (Sorry, too much Terry Pratchett).

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for confirming my suspicions and the snippet to create it programmatically. There is however one more solution, namely: create the UIImageView with a background color and add it as a subview (like in my first code snippet), and then eventually remove from superview and delete (set to nil) only when setting the imageView.image property. Though, I am not sure if that would be more memory efficient than reusing the same placeholder image in all cells as you suggested.

Comment: If you wanted to do that, no need for all the overhead of a UIImageView. UIView has all the background colour properties/methods you need. But if you use a subview, you have to manage all of it's movement, memory, autosizing etc.
If you slap a custom image into the UITableViewCell's imageview, then the cell can handle all the display itself, without much work. Unless of course, you want the flexibility...?

Comment: Actually, the square background is just a placeholder for a picture so I don't need to move it around nor resize nor do any other fancy management. Regarding the overhead for UIImageView, I am adding the placeholder in the imageView property, which expects UIImageView. That way I don't need to manage an additional subview and property in each cell.

Comment: Exactly what I'm saying. If you don't need that extra flexibility, you don't need to make your own UIImageView. So use the TableViewCell's imageView is a far better option.